# AngularJS Select drop down list is very slow in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ui

I am trying to render a select list inside a directive html template. I am using the below code to render my options inside select.

```
<select id="{{control.id}}"
        class="col-md-4 form-control"
        name="{{control.id}}"
        data-ng-model="control.selectedItem"
        data-ng-options="ctrl.value for ctrl in control.options track by ctrl.key">
</select>
```

All the options are coming in drop-down correctly and the selected item is also showing properly. The problem begins when I try to change my selection in the drop-down, and that too this problem is occurring only internet explorer, in other chrome or fire fox the drop-down list change selection is going very fast. I am trying to resolve this problem since 2 days. I have gone through so many articles as well. Since I could not able to figure out why only in IE this problem is happening.

If anybody faced the same problem please help me. I am afraid I may not able to produce the plnkr for this. If anybody can help me through skype call also it is ok for me. I will take them through my code.

Comment: Which version of the IE?

Comment: I have tested with IE9, IE10 and Edge.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I am also having the same issue.  Takes 2 min on IE, takes 2sec on Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, applying styles was taking maximum time. Trying profiling your session using [UI Responsiveness tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255009(v=vs.85).aspx) in IE. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/reduce-the-scope-and-complexity-of-style-calculations) is some tips to reduce the time of style calculations.